# Display return value as column name in sql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query in `mysql` to return all the products and it's specifications. I managed to make a query as follows:

```
select `brands`.`name`,`products`.`reference`,`specifications`.`name`,`specs-product`.`value` 

from `specs-product` 

inner join `products` on `specs-product`.`product-id`=`products`.`product-id`
inner join `specifications` on `specs-product`.`specification-id`=`specifications`.`specification-id`  
inner join `brands` on `products`.`brand-id`=`brands`.`brand-id`

where 

`specs-product`.`product-id` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

and

(
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='88' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='103' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='18' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='15' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='157' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='89' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='9' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='223' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='224' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='29' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='87' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='219' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='218' or 
`specs-product`.`specification-id`='220'
);
```

It returns all the values and works fine. But I'm trying to display the values where all the specifications of the product is shown in a single row. So in effect there will be only 8 rows for the returned result.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: that'd be a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. the workarounds get ugly fast, and cannot handle arbtrary-sized pivots. do this in your client and save yourself a lot of agony and hair pulling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
  b.name AS brand,
  p.reference AS reference,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 88
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS weight,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 103
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS toneryield,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 18
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS stdpapercapacity,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 15
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS speed,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 157
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS resolution,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 89
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS powerreqs,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 9
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS maxmonthdutycycle,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 223
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS lowprice,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 224
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS highprice,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 29
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS documentfeeder,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 87
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS dimensions,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 219
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS colorimpressions,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 218
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS blackimpressions,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM `specs-product`
    WHERE `specification_id` = 220
      AND `product_id` = p.`product_id`
  ) AS blacktonerinsqrfeet
FROM products p
INNER JOIN brands b ON b.`brand_id` = p.`brand_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a relational operation, so it cannot be done in SQL (at least, not with MySQL).

However, if you switch to MariaDB, you will be able to use a storage engine called `CONNECT`, that can be used (among many other things) to create pivot tables. See documentation:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-table-types-pivot-table-type/

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done in mysql.

```
Select group_concat(specifications.name)
..
..
Group by specs-product.product-id
```